# Array of object inside array of grouped objects with calculated total in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, grouping

as the title said, I need to push array of objects inside grouped objects. I found example  here and it goes:

```
function groupBy(array, col, value) {
    var r = [], o = {};
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        if (!o[a[col]]) {
            o[a[col]] = {};
            o[a[col]][col] = a[col];
            o[a[col]][value] = 0;
            r.push(o[a[col]]);

        }
        o[a[col]][value] += +a[value];
    });
    return r;
};

var data = [{ Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "10" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "15" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "25" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "30" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "35" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "40" }];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(groupBy(data, 'Phase', 'Value'), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

my result is:

```
[
    {
        "Phase": "Phase 1",
        "Value": 50
    },
    {
        "Phase": "Phase 2",
        "Value": 130
    }
]
```

What I want to get is that inside my grouped object is array of objects with properties: Task and Value (for each task I want value).

I tried this:

```
function groupBy(array, col, col2, value) {
    var r = [], o = {};
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        if (!o[a[col]]) {
            o[a[col]] = {};
            o[a[col]][col] = a[col];
            o[a[col]][col2] = a[col2];
            o[a[col]][value] = 0;
            r.push(o[a[col]]);

        }
        o[a[col]][value] += +a[value];
    });
    return r;
};
```

and add "Task" parameter but only I got was:

```
[
    {
        "Phase": "Phase 1",
        "Task" : "Task 1",
        "Value": 50
    },
    {
        "Phase": "Phase 2",
        "Task" : "Task 1",
        "Value": 130
    }
]
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Phase` and `Task` for the key in hash table. So the code need to be changed like this

```
function groupBy(array, col, col2, value) {
  var r = [],
    o = {};
  array.forEach(function(a) {
    // key is not 'Phase' only, it should combine 'Phase' and 'Task', others are the same.
    if (!o[a[col] + a[col2]]) {
      o[a[col] + a[col2]] = {};
      o[a[col] + a[col2]][col] = a[col];
      o[a[col] + a[col2]][col2] = a[col2];
      o[a[col] + a[col2]][value] = 0;
      r.push(o[a[col] + a[col2]]);

    }
    o[a[col] + a[col2]][value] += +a[value];
  });
  return r;
};
```

Check out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrpeextg/).